# Ruby: Thread doesn't run

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Threads in Ruby.

I created a thread but it doesn't work.
How can I fix it?

```
puts 'start'
Thread.new do
  puts 'thread'
  10.times { |i| puts i  }
end

puts 'start 2'
```

Output:

> start
>   start 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the main thread ends without the other thread executing. You have to make the main thread wait for it to finish using `Thread#join`:

```
puts 'start'
Thread.new do
  puts 'thread'
  10.times { |i| puts i  }
end.join

puts 'start 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
puts 'start'

t = Thread.new do
  puts 'thread'
  10.times { |i| puts i  }
end

t.join

puts 'start 2'
```

or

```
puts 'start'

Thread.new do
  puts 'thread'
  10.times { |i| puts i  }
end.join

puts 'start 2'
```